Beta has minimal functionality - how to direct users to fully functional version?
Working on replacing a legacy system one piece at a time. We created a minimal version for our main functions for our first release, but need to direct users to the previous version for all other tasks. This includes flows to request and schedule with accommodations.
I'm struggling with how to word/implement this to keep it concise and clear. Looking for some ideas.

"Looking for some ideas" is too broad, can you [edit] your question to make it more focused on a single answerable problem?

If you can provide a well visible banner somewhere:
"This panel is in beta stadium and is not fully functional yet. Please use the functionality of the old system instead [Button: Start Old System]"
This of course makes it necessary that the previous version can be accessed somehow.
Actually, if this is a live system, you should not show anything to the end user that is not fully functional. If this beta version is going to be released to be used by "live users". Just show them blank space and the banner. You can maybe designate a smaller team of users to have it using your beta with the dummy implementations and give you feedback on the usability.
